# Click all elements with same CssSelector or same XPath FindElements

Tags: c#, selenium, xpath, webdriver, css-selectors

In Visual Studio writing the code for Selenium WebDriver, these two codes for the same button work fine only once.

Click the button **By Css Selector:**

```
driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(".follow-text")).Click();
```

Click the button **By XPath:**

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//button[@class='user-actions-follow-button js-follow-btn follow-button btn small small-follow-btn']")).Click();
```

Until this all correct...

---

**But I want to click to all the buttons** not to only the first, and because of the `FindElements` (in plural) get me error, how can I press click to all the buttons with that same code?

Using this get error:

```
List<IWebElement> textfields = new List<IWebElement>(); 
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//button[@class='user-actions-follow-button js-follow-btn follow-button btn small small-follow-btn']")).Click();
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//button[@class='user-actions-follow-button js-follow-btn follow-button btn small small-follow-btn'][3]")).Click();
```

See the capture:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to loop through `FindElements` result and call `.Click()` on each item :

```
var result = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//button[@class='user-actions-follow-button js-follow-btn follow-button btn small small-follow-btn']"));
foreach (IWebElement element in result)
{
    element.Click();
}
```

FYI, you need to wrap the XPath in brackets to make your attempted code using XPath index works :

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("(//button[@class='user-actions-follow-button js-follow-btn follow-button btn small small-follow-btn'])[3]")).Click();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List <WebElement> list = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//button[@class='user-actions-follow-button js-follow-btn follow-button btn small small-follow-btn']"));
```

And then iterate over the list of elements contained in the list:

```
int x = 0;
while (x < list.size()) {
    WebElement element = list.get(x);
    element.click();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use something like that (note the s in findElements)

```
List<WebElement> textfields = driver.findElements(By.XPath("//button[@class='user-actions-follow-button js-follow-btn follow-button btn small small-follow-btn']"));
```

and then iterate with a for loop

```
for(WebElement elem : textfields){
    elem.click();
}
```

Comment: appears this error, What I do bad..? mm aix:  http://s22.postimg.org/d38bhviyp/QUINTO.jpg  thanks

Comment: wierd, what java version are you using, on what IDE ?

Comment: I use Java version number 7, and Selenium IDE (the last)for Firefox, writting the code in Visual Studio

Comment: As the pictures says you must have forgotten a `;`

Comment: Sorry it is my fault, it does not run because I use Webdriver C# I see now, sorry, sorry and thanks for all.

Comment: Oh I see, in that case just adapt the for loop to c# syntax as it seems to be the only problem here. I can't help you more here as I've never used C#