# Click all elements with same css RSelenium

Tags: r, web-scraping, rselenium

I'm trying to scrape a website where I have to click on multiple elements and then extract the text with `RSelenium`

I found a couple of questions on this topic, but couldn't solve my problem:
[Checking multiple checkbox with RSelenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35340253/checking-multiple-checkbox-with-rselenium)
[Click all elements with same CssSelector or same XPath FindElements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24752633/click-all-elements-with-same-cssselector-or-same-xpath-findelements)

I would like to extract the text from sentences in this search: https://eur-lex.europa.eu/search.html?typeOfCourtStatus=COURT_JUSTICE&DB_TYPE_COURT=COURT_JUSTICE&qid=1552508694151&DB_TYPE_OF_ACT=advGeneral&DTS_DOM=EU_LAW&typeOfActStatus=ADV_GENERAL&type=advanced&lang=en&SUBDOM_INIT=EU_CASE_LAW&date0=ALL:01012008%7C31122018&DTS_SUBDOM=EU_CASE_LAW&page=1

For that, I have to click on the titles and then scrape the texts.

I can do it for one:

```
browser$navigate(url)
Sys.sleep(1)
more <- browser$findElement(using = "css selector", value = ".title")
more$clickElement()
more <- browser$findElement(using = "id", value= "text")
sentences <- unlist(sapply(more, function(x){more$getElementText()}))
sentences <- unique(sentences)
```

But when I try to use `findElements` it returns the error `attempt to apply non-function`. I'm new to scraping so probably my code has more errors, but here is my attempt:

```
browser$navigate(url)
Sys.sleep(1)
more <- browser$findElements(using = "css selector", value = ".title")
for (i in 1:length(more)){
  more$clickElement()
  more <- browser$findElement(using = "id", value= "text")
  sentences <- unlist(sapply(more, function(x){more$getElementText()}))
  sentences <- unique(sentences)
  }
```

Any ideas on how can I solve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to SO. `more$clickElement()` should this be `more[i]`$clickElement()` in the for loop?

Comment: Same `attempt to apply non-function` error doing that

Comment: which line throwing that error. I see you are overwritting `more` in the loop, which will reset the values stored earlier. Try to use different variable names.

Comment: It is the `more$clickElement()` line so the second more shouldn't be affecting the outcome. Tried changing the name anyway but the error is the same.